# Scroll on an individual chart which is part of Altair Cross-Filter Dashboard

Tags: altair

[image: Verical Scroll Required on Heatmap]

Currently the dashboard looks unorganized as the heatmap is extending with vertical scroll on overall dashboard which has been saved as HTML. Is it possible to add a vertical scroll on the heatmap instead of entire page.

Comment: If those charts are part of the same Altair layout, I don't think it is possible (not 100% sure though). If they are different Altair layouts and you are manually putting them on the same HTML page, you could modify the outer `div` of the heatmap or use and iframe. There are some more details in the VegaLite docs https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#specifying-responsive-width-and-height

Comment: They are part of the same Altair layout and cross-filter is being used.